# Horário de trabalho válido

Tags: mysql, sql

Como eu faço para calcular o tempo gasto nos chamados atendidos por um funcionário? Porém sempre dentro do horário de trabalho válido, e sabendo que o horário de trabalho de um funcionário fica entre 08hs e 18hs.

Por exemplo: tabela chamado_status_log.

```
___________________________________________________________
|cod_log|cod_chamado|inicio_log |fim_log    | status_log  |
| 001   | 100       |25/07 16:00|25/07 17:00| Atendimento |
| 002   | 100       |25/07 17:00|26/07 08:30| Pausado     |
| 003   | 100       |26/07 08:30|           | Atendimento |    
|_______|___________|___________|___________|_____________|
```

Como eles podem atender vários chamados por dia, 
eles tem à possibilidade de deixar os chamados em pausa até o melhor momento para atendê-lo, inclusive deixando para um outro dia.

O cálculo do tempo gasto no atendimento do chamado eu consigo recuperar, 
porém não estou conseguindo visualizar a melhor maneira 
de deixar o cálculo das pausas dentro do horário de trabalho.
Nesse exemplo acima citado a pausa calculada desse chamado deveria ser de 1:30min, ou seja só contaria até o fim do seu horário de trabalho, e à partir do seu horário de inicio da jornada.

Minha query está desse jeito:

```
SET @HoraEntrada  = '08:00:00';
SET @HoraSaida    = '20:00:00';
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, q.isl_data_ini, q.isl_data_fim))
as `difference` 
FROM insuporte_status_log q 
WHERE hour(q.isl_data_ini) >= @HoraEntrada and hour(q.isl_data_fim) <= @HoraSaida
and  q.isl_sch_codigo = '100405-573'
and (q.isl_status = 'Pausado')
```

E mesmo assim continua contando o tempo que teoricamente deveria estar fora do range.

Como deveria ser a minha abordagem nesse caso? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: *"deixar o cálculo dentro do horário de trabalho"* o intervalo válido (horário de trabalho), tem que ser filtrado no `where`

Comment: Você tem o horário do antendimento na sua tabela? Poderia adicinar a estrutura da tabela de atendimentos e alguns exemplos de conteúdo?

Comment: O horário de atendimento é esse definido acima das 8hs às 18hs, a minha dúvida é se por exemplo eu "pausar" um atendimento hoje às 17hs e retomar amanhã às 8hs, conte somente 1 hora de pausa, e não 15 como ocorre hoje.

Comment: Editei novamente agora com alguns dados fictícios da tabela para um melhor entendimento do problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `[IF()][1]` para que quando a hora for menor que `@HoraEntrada` você mudar para a própria `@HoraEntrada` e se for maior que `@HoraSaida` também assuma a `@HoraSaida`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SET @HoraEntrada  = '08:00:00';
SET @HoraSaida    = '20:00:00';
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        SECOND,
        IF(q.isl_data_ini < HoraEntrada,
            @HoraEntrada,
            IF(q.isl_data_ini > @HoraSaida,
                @HoraSaida,
                q.isl_data_ini
            )
        ),
        IF(q.isl_data_ini < HoraEntrada,
            @HoraEntrada,
            IF(q.isl_data_fim > @HoraSaida,
                @HoraSaida,
                q.isl_data_fim
            )
        )
    )
) as `difference` 
FROM insuporte_status_log q 
WHERE q.isl_sch_codigo = '100405-573'
and (q.isl_status = 'Pausado')
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda, eu adaptei e utilizei o exemplo citado, porém mesmo assim a contagem do total do tempo em pausa continua contando o tempo que está entre a "@HoraSaida" e "@HoraEntrada", esse tempo não deve ser levado em conta.

Comment: Não tenho como testar, coloque uma estrutura para que possamos realizar alguns testes no http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: O total da pausa deveria ser 4hs e por essa estrutura a diferença está sendo de 16hs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/417be9/1